# steps to use device in place of symbian emulator using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I am using Netbeans and s60 3rd version and i have completed contact manipulation which is working fine with emulator and now i want it to be work on s60 device so what are the steps to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the MIDlet .jad and .jar file to a memory card that fits into your phone.
Use the Phone file browser to execute the .jad file.
That should install it.

Alternatively, install the phone's PC Suite software that you can download from the the phone manufacturer's website.
Connect your phone to your computer via the USB cable that should have been packaged with the phone.
The PC Suite software should be able to install a MIDlet on the phone.

jackrabbit's suggestion of using a remote web server is valid and is actually the only standard way of intalling MIDlets.
Some phones will not support a PC Suite or installation from the memory card.
Symbian phones do, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a great big while, but IIRC, you have to create an [Application Descriptor](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/learn/midp/lifecycle/#jadsnjars) (a .jad file) for your midlet and put it up on a server somewhere. You'll need to package your application in a jar and put it there as well. Then you can browse to the .jad file using your device and it will install your jar, ready for you to test.

There is probably be a more convenient way, but I never found it.